# Latex Beamer - make each item appear on new slide automatically

Tags: latex, beamer

I am looking for a way to produce a new slide for each \item in \itemize without having to use \pause or specifications in each \item for what slides to appear on. I think I came across some command once that I could place in the preamble to do exactly this but I don't remember. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item test
    \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! Is there also a way how I can turn this off and back on inside the document?

Comment: @joinijo You can switch back to the default behaviour using `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}`

Answer (score 11):

A minor addition to the accepted answer, you can toggle this behavior for each itemize environment.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item test
    \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```